# Scroll action for ScrollView not working when unit-testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-scrollview, viewswitcher

I have the following problem. I'm making *unit-tests* for a custom `DialogFragment`. This dialog has a `Scrollview`. when reaching the end of which, a `ViewSwitcher` has to switch a view.

Here is the scroll listener:

```java
ViewSwitcher vs = getDialog().findViewById(R.id.vs);
scrollView.getViewTreeObserver()
     .addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
      @Override
      public void onScrollChanged() {
           if (scrollView.getChildAt(0).getBottom()
                <= (scrollView.getHeight() + scrollView.getScrollY())) {
                vs.setDisplayedChild(1);
            } else {
                vs.setDisplayedChild(0);
            }
       }
 });
```

A test setup method:

```java
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    activity = Robolectric
        .buildActivity(FragmentTestActivity.class)
        .create()
        .resume()
        .get();

    subject = MemberConsentModal.newInstance("long text");
    subject.show(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), MemberConsentModal.TAG);
}
```

And the test method code:

```java
@Test
public void onScrolledToTopBottom_showOptionButtons() {
    final ScrollView scrollView = subject.getDialog().findViewById(R.id.member_consent_content);
    ViewSwitcher vs = subject.getDialog().findViewById(R.id.vs);

    scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);

    assertThat(vs.getDisplayedChild()).isEqualTo(1);
}
```

When debugging, I see that `addOnScrollChangedListener` is never called, though, when launching the application as on an emulator, as on a physical device, it is working correctly. How can I make the scroll view to be scrolled in testing mode?

PS.
I'm using `Robolectric` and `Mockito` for *unit-testing*.

Comment: Why don't you use espresso for testing UI?

Comment: It is not used in the project I'm working on.

Comment: Is this robolectric?

Comment: Yes, it is used in the setup method to emulate the activity and the fragment.